# Вывод через пробел Python

Tags: python

Ума не приложу, как правильно вывести массив типа integer в виде строки через пробел? Есть варианты? Массив вида:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print " ".join(map(str, z))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in z: print(i, end = " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ' '.join(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ' '.join(str(v) for v in z)
```